# servlet-context error

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have the following servlet-context, basically, I'm using springmvc and I'm trying to configure it to use @autowire on my session bean.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
        infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/ ** by efficiently serving 
        up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />


    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
        in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

     <beans:bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="annotatedClasses">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:value>org.assessme.com.entity.User</beans:value>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <beans:property name="packagesToScan" value="data" />
        <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
            <beans:props>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</beans:prop>
            </beans:props>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="org.assessme.com" />

    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="mediaTypes">
            <beans:map>
                <beans:entry key="html" value="text/html" />
                <beans:entry key="json" value="application/json" />
            </beans:map>
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="defaultViews">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:bean
                    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView">
                    <beans:property name="prefixJson" value="true" />
                </beans:bean>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>


</beans:beans>
```

The error is...

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
- Class 'org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean' not found
- Class 'org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean' not found [config set: assessment/web-context]
```

The line it refers to is

```
<beans:bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3...."
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are missing spring-orm.jar.

Make sure that this is in Project lib folder.

If you are using maven than you need to add the following

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
```